# How to add icon from project properties in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, icons

Hi
I was wondering if there is possibility to get access to project properties resources form xaml.
I need to create a menuItem icon, so normally I would do this that way

```
itemCopy = new MenuItem
                           {

                               Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(NameSpace.Properties.Resources.iconName.GetHicon())
                           };
```

However I would like to create the same icon directly from XAML without using code behind. Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the respective namespace and do a static reference, e.g.

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:Test.Properties"
    Title="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.WinTitle}}">
```

If your reference does not provide an object of the right type or a method call is necessary you could use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Icons in resx resources are of `type System.Drawing.Icon`, but WPF needs an `ImageSource`. Just change the build action of the icon to "Resource" (not "Embedded Resource"), and refer to it directly in XAML:

```
<MenuItem Icon="Resources/yourIcon.ico"...
```